# How OS control files?

Tags: c, file, operating-system

I know that each block of OS array contains one FCB. but I don't understand how OS uses them to control files. I don't understand the relation. PLZ explain simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C views each file simply as a sequential stream of bytes. Each file ends either with an `end-of-file marker` or at a specific byte number recorded in a system-maintained, administrative data structure. When a file is opened, a `stream` is associated with the file. Three files and their associated streams are automatically opened when program execution begins- the `standard input`, the `standard output` and the `standard error`. Opening a file returns a pointer to a FILE structure (defineed in `<sdtio.>`) that contains information used to process the file. This structure includes a `file descriptor`, i.e., an index into an operating system array called `open file table`. Each array element contains a  `file control block (FCB)` that the operating system uses to administer a particular file. the standard input, standard output and standard error are maniulated using file pointers `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.
**Deitel, how to program C, 6th eidition, page 420**